# Got wrong pictures while saving ZPixmap to png

Tags: image, xlib, libpng, xserver, pixmap

I want to intercept the damaged region image of the client in ProcShmPutImage of xserver. I can confirm that the image is in Zpixmap format with a depth of 24 and bits_per_pixel is 32. I use the following program to save the shm data:

```
static void dump_ZPixmap(char *data, int width, int height, int BytesPerPixel)
{
    ... ...
    int fd = open(transfile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 06666);
    if (write(fd, data, height * width * BytesPerPixel) < 0) {
        LOG_ERROR("write data failed");
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

"data" is Ximage->data. BytesPerPixel is 4.

Then I use pillow to save it to png:

```
        img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
        index = 0
        for y in range(0, height):
            for x in range(0, width):
                img.putpixel((x,y), (byte[index], byte[index + 1], byte[index + 2], byte[index + 3]))
                index += 4
        
        img.save("outputD/" + matchObj.group(1) + "-" + matchObj.group(2) + "-" + matchObj.group(3) + "-" + matchObj.group(4) + ".PNG")
```

However, I get the following erroneous image, which appears to have misaligned pixels. Why is this happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgHIe.png)

I also dump the hex data of this damage area. Here is part of it:

```
7f2fe000 7f2fe004 7f2fe008 7f2fe00c 7f2fe010 7f2fe014 7f2fe018 7f2fe01c 7f2fe020 7f2fe024 7f2fe028 7f2fe02c 7f2fe030 7f2fe034 7f2fe038 7f2fe03c 7f2fe040 7f2fe044 7f2fe048 7f2fe04c 7f2fe050 7f2fe054 7f2fe058 7f2fe05c 7f2fe060 7f2fe064 7f2fe068 7f2fe06c 7f2fe070 7f2fe074 7f2fe078 7f2fe07c 7f2fe080 7f2fe084 7f2fe088 7f2fe08c 7f2fe090 7f2fe094 7f2fe098 7f2fe09c 7f2fe0a0 7f2fe0a4 7f2fe0a8 7f2fe0ac 7f2fe0b0 7f2fe0b4 7f2fe0b8 7f2fe0bc 7f2fe0c0 7f2fe0c4 7f2fe0c8 7f2fe0cc 7f2fe0d0 7f2fe0d4 7f2fe0d8 7f2fe0dc 7f2fe0e0 7f2fe0e4 7f2fe0e8 7f2fe0ec 7f2fe0f0 7f2fe0f4 7f2fe0f8 7f2fe0fc 7f2fe100 7f2fe104 7f2fe108 7f2fe10c 7f2fe110 7f2fe114 7f2fe118 7f2fe11c 7f2fe120 7f2fe124 7f2fe128 7f2fe12c 7f2fe130 7f2fe134 7f2fe138 7f2fe13c 7f2fe140 7f2fe144 7f2fe148 7f2fe14c 7f2fe150 7f2fe154 7f2fe158 7f2fe15c 7f2fe160 7f2fe164 7f2fe168 7f2fe16c 7f2fe170 7f2fe174 7f2fe178 7f2fe17c 7f2fe180 7f2fe184 7f2fe188 7f2fe18c 7f2fe190 7f2fe194 7f2fe198 7f2fe19c 7f2fe1a0 7f2fe1a4 7f2fe1a8 7f2fe1ac 7f2fe1b0 7f2fe1b4 7f2fe1b8 7f2fe1bc 7f2fe1c0 7f2fe1c4 7f2fe1c8 7f2fe1cc 7f2fe1d0 7f2fe1d4 7f2fe1d8 7f2fe1dc 7f2fe1e0 7f2fe1e4 7f2fe1e8 7f2fe1ec 7f2fe1f0 7f2fe1f4 7f2fe1f8 7f2fe1fc 7f2fe200 7f2fe204 7f2fe208 7f2fe20c 7f2fe210 7f2fe214 7f2fe218 7f2fe21c 7f2fe220 7f2fe224 7f2fe228 7f2fe22c 7f2fe230 7f2fe234 7f2fe238 7f2fe23c 7f2fe240 7f2fe244 7f2fe248 7f2fe24c 7f2fe250 7f2fe254 7f2fe258 7f2fe25c 7f2fe260 7f2fe264 7f2fe268 7f2fe26c 7f2fe270 7f2fe274 7f2fe278 7f2fe27c 7f2fe280 7f2fe284 7f2fe288 7f2fe28c 7f2fe290 7f2fe294 7f2fe298 7f2fe29c 7f2fe2a0 7f2fe2a4 7f2fe2a8 7f2fe2ac 7f2fe2b0 7f2fe2b4 7f2fe2b8 7f2fe2bc 7f2fe2c0 7f2fe2c4 7f2fe2c8 7f2fe2cc 7f2fe2d0 7f2fe2d4 7f2fe2d8 7f2fe2dc 7f2fe2e0 7f2fe2e4 7f2fe2e8 7f2fe2ec 7f2fe2f0 7f2fe2f4 7f2fe2f8 7f2fe2fc 7f2fe300 7f2fe304 7f2fe308 7f2fe30c 7f2fe310 7f2fe314 7f2fe318 7f2fe31c 7f2fe320 7f2fe324 7f2fe328 7f2fe32c 7f2fe330 7f2fe334 7f2fe338 7f2fe33c 7f2fe340 7f2fe344 7f2fe348 7f2fe34c 7f2fe350 7f2fe354 7f2fe358 7f2fe35c 7f2fe360 7f2fe364 7f2fe368 7f2fe36c 7f2fe370 7f2fe374 7f2fe378 7f2fe37c 7f2fe380 7f2fe384 7f2fe388 7f2fe38c 7f2fe390 7f2fe394 7f2fe398 7f2fe39c 7f2fe3a0 7f2fe3a4 7f2fe3a8 7f2fe3ac 7f2fe3b0 7f2fe3b4 7f2fe3b8 7f2fe3bc 7f2fe3c0 7f2fe3c4 7f2fe3c8 7f2fe3cc 7f2fe3d0 7f2fe3d4 7f2fe3d8 7f2fe3dc 7f2fe3e0 7f2fe3e4 7f2fe3e8 7f2fe3ec 7f2fe3f0 7f2fe3f4 7f2fe3f8 7f2fe3fc 7f2fe400 7f2fe404 7f2fe408 7f2fe40c 7f2fe410 7f2fe414 7f2fe418 7f2fe41c 7f2fe420 7f2fe424 7f2fe428 7f2fe42c 7f2fe430 7f2fe434 7f2fe438 7f2fe43c 7f2fe440 7f2fe444 7f2fe448 7f2fe44c 7f2fe450 7f2fe454 7f2fe458 7f2fe45c 7f2fe460 7f2fe464 7f2fe468 7f2fe46c 7f2fe470 7f2fe474 7f2fe478 7f2fe47c 7f2fe480 7f2fe484 7f2fe488 7f2fe48c 7f2fe490 7f2fe494 7f2fe498 7f2fe49c 7f2fe4a0 7f2fe4a4 7f2fe4a8 7f2fe4ac 7f2fe4b0 7f2fe4b4 7f2fe4b8 7f2fe4bc 7f2fe4c0 7f2fe4c4 7f2fe4c8 7f2fe4cc 7f2fe4d0 7f2fe4d4 7f2fe4d8 7f2fe4dc 7f2fe4e0 7f2fe4e4 7f2fe4e8 7f2fe4ec 7f2fe4f0 7f2fe4f4 7f2fe4f8 7f2fe4fc 7f2fe500 7f2fe504 7f2fe508 7f2fe50c 7f2fe510 7f2fe514 7f2fe518 7f2fe51c 7f2fe520 7f2fe524 7f2fe528 7f2fe52c 7f2fe530 7f2fe534 7f2fe538 7f2fe53c 7f2fe540 7f2fe544 7f2fe548 7f2fe54c 7f2fe550 7f2fe554 7f2fe558 7f2fe55c 7f2fe560 7f2fe564 7f2fe568 7f2fe56c 7f2fe570 7f2fe574 7f2fe578 7f2fe57c 7f2fe580 7f2fe584 7f2fe588 7f2fe58c 7f2fe590 7f2fe594 7f2fe598 7f2fe59c 7f2fe5a0 7f2fe5a4 7f2fe5a8 7f2fe5ac 7f2fe5b0 7f2fe5b4 7f2fe5b8 7f2fe5bc 7f2fe5c0 7f2fe5c4 7f2fe5c8 7f2fe5cc 7f2fe5d0 7f2fe5d4 7f2fe5d8 7f2fe5dc 7f2fe5e0 7f2fe5e4 7f2fe5e8 7f2fe5ec 7f2fe5f0 7f2fe5f4 7f2fe5f8 7f2fe5fc 7f2fe600 7f2fe604 7f2fe608 7f2fe60c 7f2fe610 7f2fe614 7f2fe618 7f2fe61c 7f2fe620 7f2fe624 7f2fe628 7f2fe62c 7f2fe630 7f2fe634 7f2fe638 7f2fe63c 7f2fe640 7f2fe644 7f2fe648 7f2fe64c 7f2fe650 7f2fe654 7f2fe658 7f2fe65c 7f2fe660 7f2fe664 7f2fe668 7f2fe66c 7f2fe670 7f2fe674 7f2fe678 7f2fe67c 7f2fe680 7f2fe684 7f2fe688 7f2fe68c 7f2fe690 7f2fe694 7f2fe698 7f2fe69c 7f2fe6a0 7f2fe6a4 7f2fe6a8 7f2fe6ac 7f2fe6b0 7f2fe6b4 7f2fe6b8 7f2fe6bc 7f2fe6c0 7f2fe6c4 7f2fe6c8 7f2fe6cc 7f2fe6d0 7f2fe6d4 7f2fe6d8 7f2fe6dc 7f2fe6e0 7f2fe6e4 7f2fe6e8 7f2fe6ec 7f2fe6f0 7f2fe6f4 7f2fe6f8 7f2fe6fc 7f2fe700 7f2fe704 7f2fe708 7f2fe70c 7f2fe710 7f2fe714 7f2fe718 7f2fe71c 7f2fe720 7f2fe724 7f2fe728 7f2fe72c 7f2fe730 7f2fe734 7f2fe738 7f2fe73c 7f2fe740 7f2fe744 7f2fe748 7f2fe74c 7f2fe750 7f2fe754 7f2fe758 7f2fe75c 7f2fe760 7f2fe764 7f2fe768 7f2fe76c 7f2fe770 7f2fe774 7f2fe778 7f2fe77c 7f2fe780 7f2fe784 7f2fe788 7f2fe78c 7f2fe790 7f2fe794 7f2fe798 7f2fe79c 7f2fe7a0 7f2fe7a4 7f2fe7a8 7f2fe7ac 7f2fe7b0 7f2fe7b4 7f2fe7b8 7f2fe7bc 7f2fe7c0 7f2fe7c4 7f2fe7c8 7f2fe7cc 7f2fe7d0 7f2fe7d4 7f2fe7d8 7f2fe7dc 7f2fe7e0 7f2fe7e4 7f2fe7e8 7f2fe7ec 7f2fe7f0 7f2fe7f4 7f2fe7f8 7f2fe7fc 7f2fe800 7f2fe804 7f2fe808 7f2fe80c 7f2fe810 7f2fe814 7f2fe818 7f2fe81c 7f2fe820 7f2fe824 7f2fe828 7f2fe82c 7f2fe830 7f2fe834 7f2fe838 7f2fe83c 7f2fe840 7f2fe844 7f2fe848 7f2fe84c 7f2fe850 7f2fe854 7f2fe858 7f2fe85c 7f2fe860 7f2fe864 7f2fe868 7f2fe86c 7f2fe870 7f2fe874 7f2fe878 7f2fe87c 7f2fe880 7f2fe884 7f2fe888 7f2fe88c 7f2fe890 7f2fe894 7f2fe898 7f2fe89c 7f2fe8a0 7f2fe8a4 7f2fe8a8 7f2fe8ac 7f2fe8b0 7f2fe8b4 7f2fe8b8 7f2fe8bc 7f2fe8c0 7f2fe8c4 7f2fe8c8 7f2fe8cc 7f2fe8d0 7f2fe8d4 7f2fe8d8 7f2fe8dc 7f2fe8e0 7f2fe8e4 7f2fe8e8 7f2fe8ec 7f2fe8f0 7f2fe8f4 7f2fe8f8 7f2fe8fc 7f2fe900 7f2fe904 7f2fe908 7f2fe90c 7f2fe910 7f2fe914 7f2fe918 7f2fe91c 7f2fe920 7f2fe924 7f2fe928 7f2fe92c 7f2fe930 7f2fe934 7f2fe938 7f2fe93c 7f2fe940 7f2fe944 7f2fe948 7f2fe94c 7f2fe950 7f2fe954 7f2fe958 7f2fe95c 7f2fe960 7f2fe964 7f2fe968 7f2fe96c 7f2fe970 7f2fe974 7f2fe978 7f2fe97c 7f2fe980 7f2fe984 7f2fe988 7f2fe98c 7f2fe990 7f2fe994 7f2fe998 7f2fe99c 7f2fe9a0 7f2fe9a4 7f2fe9a8 7f2fe9ac 7f2fe9b0 7f2fe9b4 7f2fe9b8 7f2fe9bc 7f2fe9c0 7f2fe9c4 7f2fe9c8 7f2fe9cc 7f2fe9d0 7f2fe9d4 7f2fe9d8 7f2fe9dc 7f2fe9e0 7f2fe9e4 7f2fe9e8 7f2fe9ec 7f2fe9f0 7f2fe9f4 7f2fe9f8 7f2fe9fc 7f2fea00 7f2fea04 7f2fea08 7f2fea0c 7f2fea10 7f2fea14 7f2fea18 7f2fea1c 7f2fea20 7f2fea24 7f2fea28 7f2fea2c 7f2fea30 7f2fea34 7f2fea38 7f2fea3c 7f2fea40 7f2fea44 7f2fea48 7f2fea4c 7f2fea50 7f2fea54 7f2fea58 7f2fea5c 7f2fea60 7f2fea64 7f2fea68 7f2fea6c 7f2fea70 7f2fea74 7f2fea78 7f2fea7c 7f2fea80 7f2fea84 7f2fea88 7f2fea8c 7f2fea90 7f2fea94 7f2fea98 7f2fea9c 7f2feaa0 7f2feaa4 7f2feaa8 7f2feaac 7f2feab0 7f2feab4 7f2feab8 7f2feabc 7f2feac0 7f2feac4 7f2feac8 7f2feacc 7f2fead0 7f2fead4 7f2fead8 7f2feadc 7f2feae0 7f2feae4 7f2feae8 7f2feaec 7f2feaf0 7f2feaf4 7f2feaf8 7f2feafc 7f2feb00 7f2feb04 7f2feb08 7f2feb0c 7f2feb10 7f2feb14 7f2feb18 7f2feb1c 7f2feb20 7f2feb24 7f2feb28 7f2feb2c 7f2feb30 7f2feb34 7f2feb38 7f2feb3c 7f2feb40 7f2feb44 7f2feb48 7f2feb4c 7f2feb50 7f2feb54 7f2feb58 7f2feb5c 7f2feb60 7f2feb64 7f2feb68 7f2feb6c 7f2feb70 7f2feb74 7f2feb78 7f2feb7c 7f2feb80 7f2feb84 7f2feb88 7f2feb8c 7f2feb90 7f2feb94 7f2feb98 7f2feb9c 7f2feba0 7f2feba4 7f2feba8 7f2febac 7f2febb0 7f2febb4 7f2febb8 7f2febbc 7f2febc0 7f2febc4 7f2febc8 7f2febcc 7f2febd0 7f2febd4 7f2febd8 7f2febdc 7f2febe0 7f2febe4 7f2febe8 7f2febec 7f2febf0 7f2febf4 7f2febf8 7f2febfc 7f2fec00 7f2fec04 7f2fec08 7f2fec0c 7f2fec10 7f2fec14 7f2fec18 7f2fec1c 7f2fec20 7f2fec24 7f2fec28 7f2fec2c 7f2fec30 7f2fec34 7f2fec38 7f2fec3c 7f2fec40 7f2fec44 7f2fec48 7f2fec4c 7f2fec50 7f2fec54 7f2fec58 7f2fec5c 7f2fec60 7f2fec64 7f2fec68 7f2fec6c 7f2fec70 7f2fec74 7f2fec78 7f2fec7c 7f2fec80 7f2fec84 7f2fec88 7f2fec8c 7f2fec90 7f2fec94 7f2fec98 7f2fec9c 7f2feca0 7f2feca4 7f2feca8 7f2fecac 7f2fecb0 7f2fecb4 7f2fecb8 7f2fecbc 7f2fecc0 7f2fecc4 7f2fecc8 7f2feccc 7f2fecd0 7f2fecd4 7f2fecd8 7f2fecdc 7f2fece0 7f2fece4 7f2fece8 7f2fecec 7f2fecf0 7f2fecf4 7f2fecf8 7f2fecfc 7f2fed00 7f2fed04 7f2fed08 7f2fed0c 7f2fed10 7f2fed14 7f2fed18 7f2fed1c 7f2fed20 7f2fed24 7f2fed28 7f2fed2c 7f2fed30 7f2fed34 7f2fed38 7f2fed3c 7f2fed40 7f2fed44 7f2fed48 7f2fed4c 7f2fed50 7f2fed54 7f2fed58 7f2fed5c 7f2fed60 7f2fed64 7f2fed68 7f2fed6c 7f2fed70 7f2fed74 7f2fed78 7f2fed7c 7f2fed80 7f2fed84 7f2fed88 7f2fed8c 7f2fed90 7f2fed94 7f2fed98 7f2fed9c 7f2feda0 7f2feda4 7f2feda8 7f2fedac 7f2fedb0 7f2fedb4 7f2fedb8 7f2fedbc 7f2fedc0 7f2fedc4 7f2fedc8 7f2fedcc 7f2fedd0 7f2fedd4 7f2fedd8 7f2feddc 7f2fede0 7f2fede4 7f2fede8 7f2fedec 7f2fedf0 7f2fedf4 7f2fedf8 7f2fedfc 7f2fee00 7f2fee04 7f2fee08 7f2fee0c 7f2fee10 7f2fee14 7f2fee18 7f2fee1c 7f2fee20 7f2fee24 7f2fee28 7f2fee2c 7f2fee30 7f2fee34 7f2fee38 7f2fee3c 7f2fee40 7f2fee44 7f2fee48 7f2fee4c 7f2fee50 7f2fee54 7f2fee58 7f2fee5c 7f2fee60 7f2fee64 7f2fee68 7f2fee6c 7f2fee70 7f2fee74 7f2fee78 7f2fee7c 7f2fee80 7f2fee84 7f2fee88 7f2fee8c 7f2fee90 7f2fee94 7f2fee98 7f2fee9c 7f2feea0 7f2feea4 7f2feea8 7f2feeac 7f2feeb0 7f2feeb4 7f2feeb8 7f2feebc 7f2feec0 7f2feec4 7f2feec8 7f2feecc 7f2feed0 7f2feed4 7f2feed8 7f2feedc 7f2feee0 7f2feee4 7f2feee8 7f2feeec 7f2feef0 7f2feef4 7f2feef8 7f2feefc 7f2fef00 7f2fef04 7f2fef08 7f2fef0c 7f2fef10 7f2fef14 7f2fef18 7f2fef1c 7f2fef20 7f2fef24 7f2fef28 7f2fef2c 7f2fef30 7f2fef34 7f2fef38 7f2fef3c 7f2fef40 7f2fef44 7f2fef48 7f2fef4c 7f2fef50 7f2fef54 7f2fef58 7f2fef5c 7f2fef60 7f2fef64 7f2fef68 7f2fef6c 7f2fef70 7f2fef74 7f2fef78 7f2fef7c 7f2fef80 7f2fef84 7f2fef88 7f2fef8c 7f2fef90 7f2fef94 7f2fef98 7f2fef9c 7f2fefa0 7f2fefa4 7f2fefa8 7f2fefac 7f2fefb0 7f2fefb4 7f2fefb8 7f2fefbc 7f2fefc0 7f2fefc4 7f2fefc8 7f2fefcc 7f2fefd0 7f2fefd4 7f2fefd8 7f2fefdc 7f2fefe0 7f2fefe4 7f2fefe8 7f2fefec 7f2feff0 7f2feff4 7f2feff8 7f2feffc 7f2ff000 7f2ff004 7f2ff008 7f2ff00c 7f2ff010 7f2ff014 7f2ff018 7f2ff01c 7f2ff020 7f2ff024 7f2ff028 7f2ff02c 7f2ff030 7f2ff034 7f2ff038 7f2ff03c 7f2ff040 7f2ff044 7f2ff048 7f2ff04c 7f2ff050 7f2ff054 7f2ff058 7f2ff05c 7f2ff060 7f2ff064 7f2ff068 7f2ff06c 7f2ff070 7f2ff074 7f2ff078 7f2ff07c 7f2ff080 7f2ff084 7f2ff088 7f2ff08c 7f2ff090 7f2ff094 7f2ff098 7f2ff09c 7f2ff0a0 7f2ff0a4 7f2ff0a8 7f2ff0ac 7f2ff0b0 7f2ff0b4 7f2ff0b8 7f2ff0bc 7f2ff0c0 7f2ff0c4 7f2ff0c8 7f2ff0cc 7f2ff0d0 7f2ff0d4 7f2ff0d8 7f2ff0dc 7f2ff0e0 7f2ff0e4 7f2ff0e8 7f2ff0ec 7f2ff0f0 7f2ff0f4 7f2ff0f8 7f2ff0fc 7f2ff100 7f2ff104 7f2ff108 7f2ff10c 7f2ff110 7f2ff114 7f2ff118 7f2ff11c 7f2ff120 7f2ff124 7f2ff128 7f2ff12c 7f2ff130 7f2ff134 7f2ff138 7f2ff13c 7f2ff140 7f2ff144 7f2ff148 7f2ff14c 7f2ff150 7f2ff154 7f2ff158 7f2ff15c 7f2ff160 7f2ff164 7f2ff168 7f2ff16c 7f2ff170 7f2ff174 7f2ff178 7f2ff17c 7f2ff180 7f2ff184 7f2ff188 7f2ff18c 7f2ff190 7f2ff194 7f2ff198 7f2ff19c 7f2ff1a0 7f2ff1a4 7f2ff1a8 7f2ff1ac 7f2ff1b0 7f2ff1b4 7f2ff1b8 7f2ff1bc 7f2ff1c0 7f2ff1c4 7f2ff1c8 7f2ff1cc 7f2ff1d0 7f2ff1d4 7f2ff1d8 7f2ff1dc 7f2ff1e0 7f2ff1e4 7f2ff1e8 7f2ff1ec 7f2ff1f0 7f2ff1f4 7f2ff1f8 7f2ff1fc 7f2ff200 7f2ff204 7f2ff208 7f2ff20c 7f2ff210 7f2ff214 7f2ff218 7f2ff21c 7f2ff220 7f2ff224 7f2ff228 7f2ff22c 7f2ff230 7f2ff234 7f2ff238 7f2ff23c 7f2ff240 7f2ff244 7f2ff248 7f2ff24c 7f2ff250 7f2ff254 7f2ff258 7f2ff25c 7f2ff260 7f2ff264 7f2ff268 7f2ff26c 7f2ff270 7f2ff274 7f2ff278 7f2ff27c 7f2ff280 7f2ff284 7f2ff288 7f2ff28c 7f2ff290 7f2ff294 7f2ff298 7f2ff29c 7f2ff2a0 7f2ff2a4 7f2ff2a8 7f2ff2ac 7f2ff2b0 7f2ff2b4 7f2ff2b8 7f2ff2bc 7f2ff2c0 7f2ff2c4 7f2ff2c8 7f2ff2cc 7f2ff2d0 7f2ff2d4 7f2ff2d8 7f2ff2dc 7f2ff2e0 7f2ff2e4 7f2ff2e8 7f2ff2ec 7f2ff2f0 7f2ff2f4 7f2ff2f8 7f2ff2fc 7f2ff300 7f2ff304 7f2ff308 7f2ff30c 7f2ff310 7f2ff314 7f2ff318 7f2ff31c 7f2ff320 7f2ff324 7f2ff328 7f2ff32c 7f2ff330 7f2ff334 7f2ff338 7f2ff33c 7f2ff340 7f2ff344 7f2ff348 7f2ff34c 7f2ff350 7f2ff354 7f2ff358 7f2ff35c 7f2ff360 7f2ff364 7f2ff368 7f2ff36c 7f2ff370 7f2ff374 7f2ff378 7f2ff37c 7f2ff380 7f2ff384 7f2ff388 7f2ff38c 7f2ff390 7f2ff394 7f2ff398 7f2ff39c 7f2ff3a0 7f2ff3a4 7f2ff3a8 7f2ff3ac 7f2ff3b0 7f2ff3b4 7f2ff3b8 7f2ff3bc 7f2ff3c0 7f2ff3c4 7f2ff3c8 7f2ff3cc 7f2ff3d0 7f2ff3d4 7f2ff3d8 7f2ff3dc 7f2ff3e0 7f2ff3e4 7f2ff3e8 7f2ff3ec 7f2ff3f0 7f2ff3f4 7f2ff3f8 7f2ff3fc 7f2ff400 7f2ff404 7f2ff408 7f2ff40c 7f2ff410 7f2ff414 7f2ff418 7f2ff41c 7f2ff420 7f2ff424 7f2ff428 7f2ff42c 7f2ff430 7f2ff434 7f2ff438 7f2ff43c 7f2ff440 7f2ff444 7f2ff448 7f2ff44c 7f2ff450 7f2ff454 7f2ff458 7f2ff45c 7f2ff460 7f2ff464 7f2ff468 7f2ff46c 7f2ff470 7f2ff474 7f2ff478 7f2ff47c 7f2ff480 7f2ff484 7f2ff488 7f2ff48c 7f2ff490 7f2ff494 7f2ff498 7f2ff49c 7f2ff4a0 7f2ff4a4 7f2ff4a8 7f2ff4ac 7f2ff4b0 7f2ff4b4 7f2ff4b8 7f2ff4bc 7f2ff4c0 7f2ff4c4 7f2ff4c8 7f2ff4cc 7f2ff4d0 7f2ff4d4 7f2ff4d8 7f2ff4dc 7f2ff4e0 7f2ff4e4 7f2ff4e8 7f2ff4ec 7f2ff4f0 7f2ff4f4 7f2ff4f8 7f2ff4fc 7f2ff500 7f2ff504 7f2ff508 7f2ff50c 7f2ff510 7f2ff514 7f2ff518 7f2ff51c 7f2ff520 7f2ff524 7f2ff528 7f2ff52c 7f2ff530 7f2ff534 7f2ff538 7f2ff53c 7f2ff540 7f2ff544 7f2ff548 7f2ff54c 7f2ff550 7f2ff554 7f2ff558 7f2ff55c 7f2ff560 7f2ff564 7f2ff568 7f2ff56c 7f2ff570 7f2ff574 7f2ff578 7f2ff57c 7f2ff580 7f2ff584 7f2ff588 7f2ff58c 7f2ff590 7f2ff594 7f2ff598 7f2ff59c 7f2ff5a0 7f2ff5a4 7f2ff5a8 7f2ff5ac 7f2ff5b0 7f2ff5b4 7f2ff5b8 7f2ff5bc 7f2ff5c0 7f2ff5c4 7f2ff5c8 7f2ff5cc 7f2ff5d0 7f2ff5d4 7f2ff5d8 7f2ff5dc 7f2ff5e0 7f2ff5e4 7f2ff5e8 7f2ff5ec 7f2ff5f0 7f2ff5f4 7f2ff5f8 7f2ff5fc 7f2ff600 7f2ff604 7f2ff608 7f2ff60c 7f2ff610 7f2ff614 7f2ff618 7f2ff61c 7f2ff620 7f2ff624 7f2ff628 7f2ff62c 7f2ff630 7f2ff634 7f2ff638 7f2ff63c 7f2ff640 7f2ff644 7f2ff648 7f2ff64c 7f2ff650 7f2ff654 7f2ff658 7f2ff65c 7f2ff660 7f2ff664 7f2ff668 7f2ff66c 7f2ff670 7f2ff674 7f2ff678 7f2ff67c 7f2ff680 7f2ff684 7f2ff688 7f2ff68c 7f2ff690 7f2ff694 7f2ff698 7f2ff69c 7f2ff6a0 7f2ff6a4 7f2ff6a8 7f2ff6ac 7f2ff6b0 7f2ff6b4 7f2ff6b8 7f2ff6bc 7f2ff6c0 7f2ff6c4 7f2ff6c8 7f2ff6cc 7f2ff6d0 7f2ff6d4 7f2ff6d8 7f2ff6dc 7f2ff6e0 7f2ff6e4 7f2ff6e8 7f2ff6ec 7f2ff6f0 7f2ff6f4 7f2ff6f8 7f2ff6fc 7f2ff700 7f2ff704 7f2ff708 7f2ff70c 7f2ff710 7f2ff714 7f2ff718 7f2ff71c 7f2ff720 7f2ff724 7f2ff728 7f2ff72c 7f2ff730 7f2ff734 7f2ff738 7f2ff73c 7f2ff740 7f2ff744 7f2ff748 7f2ff74c 7f2ff750 7f2ff754 7f2ff758 7f2ff75c 7f2ff760 7f2ff764 7f2ff768 7f2ff76c 7f2ff770 7f2ff774 7f2ff778 7f2ff77c 7f2ff780 7f2ff784 7f2ff788 7f2ff78c 7f2ff790 7f2ff794 7f2ff798 7f2ff79c 7f2ff7a0 7f2ff7a4 7f2ff7a8 7f2ff7ac 7f2ff7b0 7f2ff7b4 7f2ff7b8 7f2ff7bc 7f2ff7c0 7f2ff7c4 7f2ff7c8 7f2ff7cc 7f2ff7d0 7f2ff7d4 7f2ff7d8 7f2ff7dc 7f2ff7e0 7f2ff7e4 7f2ff7e8 7f2ff7ec 7f2ff7f0 7f2ff7f4 7f2ff7f8 7f2ff7fc 7f2ff800 7f2ff804 7f2ff808 7f2ff80c 7f2ff810 7f2ff814 7f2ff818 7f2ff81c 7f2ff820 7f2ff824 7f2ff828 7f2ff82c 7f2ff830 7f2ff834 7f2ff838 7f2ff83c 7f2ff840 7f2ff844 7f2ff848 7f2ff84c 7f2ff850 7f2ff854 7f2ff858 7f2ff85c 7f2ff860 7f2ff864 7f2ff868 7f2ff86c 7f2ff870 7f2ff874 7f2ff878 7f2ff87c 7f2ff880 7f2ff884 7f2ff888 7f2ff88c 7f2ff890 7f2ff894 7f2ff898 7f2ff89c 7f2ff8a0 7f2ff8a4 7f2ff8a8 7f2ff8ac 7f2ff8b0 7f2ff8b4 7f2ff8b8 7f2ff8bc 7f2ff8c0 7f2ff8c4 7f2ff8c8 7f2ff8cc 7f2ff8d0 7f2ff8d4 7f2ff8d8 7f2ff8dc 7f2ff8e0 7f2ff8e4 7f2ff8e8 7f2ff8ec 7f2ff8f0 7f2ff8f4 7f2ff8f8 7f2ff8fc 7f2ff900 7f2ff904 7f2ff908 7f2ff90c 7f2ff910 7f2ff914 7f2ff918 7f2ff91c 7f2ff920 7f2ff924 7f2ff928 7f2ff92c 7f2ff930 7f2ff934 7f2ff938 7f2ff93c 7f2ff940 7f2ff944 7f2ff948 7f2ff94c 7f2ff950 7f2ff954 7f2ff958 7f2ff95c 7f2ff960 7f2ff964 7f2ff968 7f2ff96c 7f2ff970 7f2ff974 7f2ff978 7f2ff97c 7f2ff980 7f2ff984 7f2ff988 7f2ff98c 7f2ff990 7f2ff994 7f2ff998 7f2ff99c 7f2ff9a0 7f2ff9a4 7f2ff9a8 7f2ff9ac 7f2ff9b0 7f2ff9b4 7f2ff9b8 7f2ff9bc 7f2ff9c0 7f2ff9c4 7f2ff9c8 7f2ff9cc 7f2ff9d0 7f2ff9d4 7f2ff9d8 7f2ff9dc 7f2ff9e0 7f2ff9e4 7f2ff9e8 7f2ff9ec 7f2ff9f0 7f2ff9f4 7f2ff9f8 7f2ff9fc 7f2ffa00 7f2ffa04 7f2ffa08 7f2ffa0c 7f2ffa10 7f2ffa14 7f2ffa18 7f2ffa1c 7f2ffa20 7f2ffa24 7f2ffa28 7f2ffa2c 7f2ffa30 7f2ffa34 7f2ffa38 7f2ffa3c 7f2ffa40 7f2ffa44 7f2ffa48 7f2ffa4c 7f2ffa50 7f2ffa54 7f2ffa58 7f2ffa5c 7f2ffa60 7f2ffa64 7f2ffa68 7f2ffa6c 7f2ffa70 7f2ffa74 7f2ffa78 7f2ffa7c 7f2ffa80 7f2ffa84 7f2ffa88 7f2ffa8c 7f2ffa90 7f2ffa94 7f2ffa98 7f2ffa9c 7f2ffaa0 7f2ffaa4 7f2ffaa8 7f2ffaac 7f2ffab0 7f2ffab4 7f2ffab8 7f2ffabc 7f2ffac0 7f2ffac4 7f2ffac8 7f2ffacc 7f2ffad0 7f2ffad4 7f2ffad8 7f2ffadc 7f2ffae0 7f2ffae4 7f2ffae8 7f2ffaec 7f2ffaf0 7f2ffaf4 7f2ffaf8 7f2ffafc 7f2ffb00 7f2ffb04 7f2ffb08 7f2ffb0c 7f2ffb10 7f2ffb14 7f2ffb18 7f2ffb1c 7f2ffb20 7f2ffb24 7f2ffb28 7f2ffb2c 7f2ffb30 7f2ffb34 7f2ffb38 7f2ffb3c 7f2ffb40 7f2ffb44 7f2ffb48 7f2ffb4c 7f2ffb50 7f2ffb54 7f2ffb58 7f2ffb5c 7f2ffb60 7f2ffb64 7f2ffb68 7f2ffb6c 7f2ffb70 7f2ffb74 7f2ffb78 7f2ffb7c 7f2ffb80 7f2ffb84 7f2ffb88 7f2ffb8c 7f2ffb90 7f2ffb94 7f2ffb98 7f2ffb9c 7f2ffba0 7f2ffba4 7f2ffba8 7f2ffbac 7f2ffbb0 7f2ffbb4 7f2ffbb8 7f2ffbbc 7f2ffbc0 7f2ffbc4 7f2ffbc8 7f2ffbcc 7f2ffbd0 7f2ffbd4 7f2ffbd8 7f2ffbdc 7f2ffbe0 7f2ffbe4 7f2ffbe8 7f2ffbec 7f2ffbf0 7f2ffbf4 7f2ffbf8 7f2ffbfc 7f2ffc00 7f2ffc04 7f2ffc08 7f2ffc0c 7f2ffc10 7f2ffc14 7f2ffc18 7f2ffc1c 7f2ffc20 7f2ffc24 7f2ffc28 7f2ffc2c 7f2ffc30 7f2ffc34 7f2ffc38 7f2ffc3c 7f2ffc40 7f2ffc44 7f2ffc48 7f2ffc4c 7f2ffc50 7f2ffc54 7f2ffc58 7f2ffc5c 7f2ffc60 7f2ffc64 7f2ffc68 7f2ffc6c 7f2ffc70 7f2ffc74 7f2ffc78 7f2ffc7c 7f2ffc80 7f2ffc84 7f2ffc88 7f2ffc8c 7f2ffc90 7f2ffc94 7f2ffc98 7f2ffc9c 7f2ffca0 7f2ffca4 7f2ffca8 7f2ffcac 7f2ffcb0 7f2ffcb4 7f2ffcb8 7f2ffcbc 7f2ffcc0 7f2ffcc4 7f2ffcc8 7f2ffccc 7f2ffcd0 7f2ffcd4 7f2ffcd8 7f2ffcdc 7f2ffce0 7f2ffce4 7f2ffce8 7f2ffcec 7f2ffcf0 7f2ffcf4 7f2ffcf8 7f2ffcfc 7f2ffd00 7f2ffd04 7f2ffd08 7f2ffd0c 7f2ffd10 7f2ffd14 7f2ffd18 7f2ffd1c 7f2ffd20 7f2ffd24 7f2ffd28 7f2ffd2c 7f2ffd30 7f2ffd34 7f2ffd38 7f2ffd3c 7f2ffd40 7f2ffd44 7f2ffd48 7f2ffd4c 7f2ffd50 7f2ffd54 7f2ffd58 7f2ffd5c 7f2ffd60 7f2ffd64 7f2ffd68 7f2ffd6c 7f2ffd70 7f2ffd74 7f2ffd78 7f2ffd7c 7f2ffd80 7f2ffd84 7f2ffd88 7f2ffd8c 7f2ffd90 7f2ffd94 7f2ffd98 7f2ffd9c 7f2ffda0 7f2ffda4 7f2ffda8 7f2ffdac 7f2ffdb0 7f2ffdb4 7f2ffdb8 7f2ffdbc 7f2ffdc0 7f2ffdc4 7f2ffdc8 7f2ffdcc 7f2ffdd0 7f2ffdd4 7f2ffdd8 7f2ffddc 7f2ffde0 7f2ffde4 7f2ffde8 7f2ffdec 7f2ffdf0 7f2ffdf4 7f2ffdf8 7f2ffdfc 7f2ffe00 7f2ffe04 7f2ffe08 7f2ffe0c 7f2ffe10 7f2ffe14 7f2ffe18 7f2ffe1c 7f2ffe20 7f2ffe24 7f2ffe28 7f2ffe2c 7f2ffe30 7f2ffe34 7f2ffe38 7f2ffe3c 7f2ffe40 7f2ffe44 7f2ffe48 7f2ffe4c 7f2ffe50 7f2ffe54 7f2ffe58 7f2ffe5c 7f2ffe60 7f2ffe64 7f2ffe68 7f2ffe6c 7f2ffe70 7f2ffe74 7f2ffe78 7f2ffe7c 7f2ffe80 7f2ffe84 7f2ffe88 7f2ffe8c 7f2ffe90 7f2ffe94 7f2ffe98 7f2ffe9c 7f2ffea0 7f2ffea4 7f2ffea8 7f2ffeac 7f2ffeb0 7f2ffeb4 7f2ffeb8 7f2ffebc 7f2ffec0 7f2ffec4 7f2ffec8 7f2ffecc 7f2ffed0 7f2ffed4 7f2ffed8 7f2ffedc 7f2ffee0 7f2ffee4 7f2ffee8 7f2ffeec 7f2ffef0 7f2ffef4 7f2ffef8 7f2ffefc 7f2fff00 7f2fff04 7f2fff08 7f2fff0c 7f2fff10 7f2fff14 7f2fff18 7f2fff1c 7f2fff20 7f2fff24 7f2fff28 7f2fff2c 7f2fff30 7f2fff34 7f2fff38 7f2fff3c 7f2fff40 7f2fff44 7f2fff48 7f2fff4c 7f2fff50 7f2fff54 7f2fff58 7f2fff5c 7f2fff60 7f2fff64 7f2fff68 7f2fff6c 7f2fff70 7f2fff74 7f2fff78 7f2fff7c 7f2fff80 7f2fff84 7f2fff88 7f2fff8c 7f2fff90 7f2fff94 7f2fff98 7f2fff9c 7f2fffa0 7f2fffa4 7f2fffa8 7f2fffac 7f2fffb0 7f2fffb4 7f2fffb8 7f2fffbc 7f2fffc0 7f2fffc4 7f2fffc8 7f2fffcc 7f2fffd0 7f2fffd4 7f2fffd8 7f2fffdc 7f2fffe0 7f2fffe4 7f2fffe8 7f2fffec 7f2ffff0 7f2ffff4 7f2ffff8 7f2ffffc 7f300000 7f300004 7f300008 7f30000c 7f300010 7f300014 7f300018 7f30001c 7f300020 7f300024 7f300028 7f30002c 7f300030 7f300034 7f300038 7f30003c 7f300040 7f300044 7f300048 7f30004c 7f300050 7f300054 7f300058 7f30005c 7f300060 7f300064 7f300068 7f30006c 7f300070 7f300074 7f300078 7f30007c 7f300080 7f300084 7f300088 7f30008c 7f300090 7f300094 7f300098 7f30009c 7f3000a0 7f3000a4 7f3000a8 7f3000ac 7f3000b0 7f3000b4 7f3000b8 7f3000bc 7f3000c0 7f3000c4 7f3000c8 7f3000cc 7f3000d0 7f3000d4 7f3000d8 7f3000dc 7f3000e0 7f3000e4 7f3000e8 7f3000ec 7f3000f0 7f3000f4 7f3000f8 7f3000fc 7f300100 7f300104 7f300108 7f30010c 7f300110 7f300114 7f300118 7f30011c 7f300120 7f300124 7f300128 7f30012c 7f300130 7f300134 7f300138 7f30013c 7f300140 7f300144 7f300148 7f30014c 7f300150 7f300154 7f300158 7f30015c 7f300160 7f300164 7f300168 7f30016c 7f300170 7f300174 7f300178 7f30017c 7f300180 7f300184 7f300188 7f30018c 7f300190 7f300194 7f300198 7f30019c 7f3001a0 7f3001a4 7f3001a8 7f3001ac 7f3001b0 7f3001b4 7f3001b8 7f3001bc 7f3001c0 7f3001c4 7f3001c8 7f3001cc 7f3001d0 7f3001d4 7f3001d8 7f3001dc 7f3001e0 7f3001e4 7f3001e8 7f3001ec 7f3001f0 7f3001f4 7f3001f8 7f3001fc 7f300200 7f300204 7f300208 7f30020c 7f300210 7f300214 7f300218 7f30021c 7f300220 7f300224 7f300228 7f30022c 7f300230 7f300234 7f300238 7f30023c 7f300240 7f300244 7f300248 7f30024c 7f300250 7f300254 7f300258 7f30025c 7f300260 7f300264 7f300268 7f30026c 7f300270 7f300274 7f300278 7f30027c 7f300280 7f300284 7f300288 7f30028c 7f300290 7f300294 7f300298 7f30029c 7f3002a0 7f3002a4 7f3002a8 7f3002ac 7f3002b0 7f3002b4 7f3002b8 7f3002bc 7f3002c0 7f3002c4 7f3002c8 7f3002cc 7f3002d0 7f3002d4 7f3002d8 7f3002dc 7f3002e0 7f3002e4 7f3002e8 7f3002ec 7f3002f0 7f3002f4 7f3002f8 7f3002fc 7f300300 7f300304 7f300308 7f30030c 7f300310 7f300314 7f300318 7f30031c 7f300320 7f300324 7f300328 7f30032c 7f300330 7f300334 7f300338 7f30033c 7f300340 7f300344 7f300348 7f30034c 7f300350 7f300354 7f300358 7f30035c 7f300360 7f300364 7f300368 7f30036c 7f300370 7f300374 7f300378 7f30037c 7f300380 7f300384 7f300388 7f30038c 7f300390 7f300394 7f300398 7f30039c 7f3003a0 7f3003a4 7f3003a8 7f3003ac 7f3003b0 7f3003b4 7f3003b8 7f3003bc 7f3003c0 7f3003c4 7f3003c8 7f3003cc 7f3003d0 7f3003d4 7f3003d8 7f3003dc 7f3003e0 7f3003e4 7f3003e8 7f3003ec 7f3003f0 7f3003f4 7f3003f8 7f3003fc 7f300400 7f300404 7f300408 7f30040c 7f300410 7f300414 7f300418 7f30041c 7f300420 7f300424 7f300428 7f30042c 7f300430 7f300434 7f300438 7f30043c 7f300440 7f300444 7f300448 7f30044c 7f300450 7f300454 7f300458 7f30045c 7f300460 7f300464 7f300468 7f30046c 7f300470 7f300474 7f300478 7f30047c 7f300480 7f300484 7f300488 7f30048c 7f300490 7f300494 7f300498 7f30049c 7f3004a0 7f3004a4 7f3004a8 7f3004ac 7f3004b0 7f3004b4 7f3004b8 7f3004bc 7f3004c0 7f3004c4 7f3004c8 7f3004cc 7f3004d0 7f3004d4 7f3004d8 7f3004dc 7f3004e0 7f3004e4 7f3004e8 7f3004ec 7f3004f0 7f3004f4 7f3004f8 7f3004fc 7f300500 7f300504 7f300508 7f30050c 7f300510 7f300514 7f300518 7f30051c 7f300520 7f300524 7f300528 7f30052c 7f300530 7f300534 7f300538 7f30053c 7f300540 7f300544 7f300548 7f30054c 7f300550 7f300554 7f300558 7f30055c 7f300560 7f300564 7f300568 7f30056c 7f300570 7f300574 7f300578 7f30057c 7f300580 7f300584 7f300588 7f30058c 7f300590 7f300594 7f300598 7f30059c 7f3005a0 7f3005a4 7f3005a8 7f3005ac 7f3005b0 7f3005b4 7f3005b8 7f3005bc 7f3005c0 7f3005c4 7f3005c8 7f3005cc 7f3005d0 7f3005d4 7f3005d8 7f3005dc 7f3005e0 7f3005e4 7f3005e8 7f3005ec 7f3005f0 7f3005f4 7f3005f8 7f3005fc 7f300600 7f300604 7f300608 7f30060c 7f300610 7f300614 7f300618 7f30061c 7f300620 7f300624 7f300628 7f30062c 7f300630 7f300634 7f300638 7f30063c 7f300640 7f300644 7f300648 7f30064c 7f300650 7f300654 7f300658 7f30065c 7f300660 7f300664 7f300668 7f30066c 7f300670 7f300674 7f300678 7f30067c 7f300680 7f300684 7f300688 7f30068c 7f300690 7f300694 7f300698 7f30069c 7f3006a0 7f3006a4 7f3006a8 7f3006ac 7f3006b0 7f3006b4 7f3006b8 7f3006bc 7f3006c0 7f3006c4 7f3006c8 7f3006cc 7f3006d0 7f3006d4 7f3006d8 7f3006dc 7f3006e0 7f3006e4 7f3006e8 7f3006ec 7f3006f0 7f3006f4 7f3006f8 7f3006fc 7f300700 7f300704 7f300708 7f30070c 7f300710 7f300714 7f300718 7f30071c 7f300720 7f300724 7f300728 7f30072c 7f300730 7f300734 7f300738 7f30073c 7f300740 7f300744 7f300748 7f30074c 7f300750 7f300754 7f300758 7f30075c 7f300760 7f300764 7f300768 7f30076c 7f300770 7f300774 7f300778 7f30077c 7f300780 7f300784 7f300788 7f30078c 7f300790 7f300794 7f300798 7f30079c 7f3007a0 7f3007a4 7f3007a8 7f3007ac 7f3007b0 7f3007b4 7f3007b8 7f3007bc 7f3007c0 7f3007c4 7f3007c8 7f3007cc 7f3007d0 7f3007d4 7f3007d8 7f3007dc 7f3007e0 7f3007e4 7f3007e8 7f3007ec 7f3007f0 7f3007f4 7f3007f8 7f3007fc 7f300800 7f300804 7f300808 7f30080c 7f300810 7f300814 7f300818 7f30081c 7f300820 7f300824 7f300828 7f30082c 7f300830 7f300834 7f300838 7f30083c 7f300840 7f300844 7f300848 7f30084c 7f300850 7f300854 7f300858 7f30085c 7f300860 7f300864 7f300868 7f30086c 7f300870 7f300874 7f300878 7f30087c 7f300880 7f300884 7f300888 7f30088c 7f300890 7f300894 7f300898 7f30089c 7f3008a0 7f3008a4 7f3008a8 7f3008ac 7f3008b0 7f3008b4 7f3008b8 7f3008bc 7f3008c0 7f3008c4 7f3008c8 7f3008cc 7f3008d0 7f3008d4 7f3008d8 7f3008dc 7f3008e0 7f3008e4 7f3008e8 7f3008ec 7f3008f0 7f3008f4 7f3008f8 7f3008fc
```

By the way, it should be looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnfE7.png)

Please let me know the correct conversion method, or provide some clues for possible corrections.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. No need to include all the X11 stuff, just hardcode the image buffer.

Comment: You have 24 bit depth, but what is the pixel size? See bits_per_pixel in XImage. You can have 24 or 32 bits per pixel. In any case there is no alpha channel so PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB_ALPHA is not appropriate.